# Axis2 Error - No such method sayHello in class HelloAxisService

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to implement a simple example in axis2. I created the Service class and xml, generated aar and exploded in services directory. I can notice my service and operation sayHello, but when testing the webservice it says no such method sayHello in HelloAxisService which is my class.

Here is the services.xml

```
<service name="HelloAxisService">

<description>Hello Axis service</description>

        <messageReceivers>
   <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>

    <parameter name="ServiceClass">com.my.axis.HelloAxisService</parameter>

</service>
```

and here is my class

```
package com.my.axis;

public class HelloAxisService {

    private String sayHello(String name){

        return "Hello"+ name;
    }
}
```

my url is `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloAxisService/sayHello?name=dude`

Though the service is present in list of services as below, I am getting the error both in the browser as well as Client program using axiom

```
Available services

HelloAxisService

Service EPR : http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloAxisService
Service Description : No description available for this service

Service Status : Active
Available Operations
sayHello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some careful observation at the code, found the problem. It was `private` access modifier for the method sayHello.Changing it to `public` did the thing for me.